# PHP ZipArchive can't read more then 21797 files inside

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I need to extract from zip file data.zip only one file for example 188139.xml

File contains folder with more than 88000 files. But after open - it shows me 21797 files and can't open file with big index (which is truly there). But opens 1.xml, 200.xml etc.

So it looks like limitation. Is there any suggestions how to open needed file?

Comment: And that limitation don't depend from environment. I have same on Windows local machine and on production CentOS server.

Comment: Actually if I use extractTo function - only 21797 files extracted. I've also tried PclZip library - same luck. But when I'm extracting using windows zip - all files available. I've also analized size of readed files: 42232783 compressed and 260875698 uncompressed. Total file size 171.3Mb

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it a bug of library. Fixed with alternative use of execute() function.